# What are the countable groups for which each complex representation is semisimple?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Each complex representation of a finite group is semisimple (i.e. decomposes into a direct sum of irreducible complex representations).

**Question**: What are the countable groups satisfying the same property?

*Remark*: We do not restrict to finite dimensional representations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The characterization is two-way: all $\mathbb C$ representations are semisimple iff $G$ is finite.
(Corollary page 660 in [Connell, Ian G. On the group ring. Canad. J. Math. 15 1963 650--685](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/29E2EC3F9179FB3C6225A26EC88CBB77/S0008414X00029849a.pdf/on_the_group_ring.pdf))

This is essentially what [Maschke's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem) is about. I don't think finite dimensionality of representations comes into play.

Comment: Or something might be escaping my notice... this is what the question seems like to me. You might have to tell me why it isn't this simple.

Comment: I don't see an 'iff' in Maschke's theorem. How does the converse follow from it?

Comment: @lisyarus Hmm, interesting, I didn't realize the wiki article only apparently has "the classical statement."  The two-way statement appears in Connell's *On the group ring* and Lam's *First course in noncommutative rings* Theorem 6.1

Comment: @lisyarus Oh, well actually they have an entire section dedicated to the converse. Did you see that part?

Comment: You mean the wiki article? Yes, but it only talks about the case of the characteristic dividing $|G|$, and nothing about the case of infinite groups.

Comment: @lisyarus Interesting. Every time I think it covers the basic statement it turns out it doesn’t. I would recommend Connell’s paper, which is both accessible and easy to read.

Comment: Thank you for the reference! I've found Connell's paper, but I'm failing to find the relevant part (it is ~70 pages). Could you, please, point to the relevant page/chapter?

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux The augmentation ideal (kernel of $\sum a_g g \mapsto \sum a_g$) of $F[\mathbb Z]$ is a subrepresentation, but not a direct summand.

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux I think you meant $\begin{pmatrix}1 & n \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @lisyarus: Yes! A non-semisimple complex representation of $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ is: $$n \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
1 & n\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @lisyarus: The generalized Maschke theorem  is [here](https://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cjm/v15/cjm1963v15.0650-0685.pdf) Corollary page 660.

Comment: @lisyarus I meant [this version](https://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cjm/v15/cjm1963v15.0650-0685.pdf) which is 36 pages and has very suggestively labeled sections.  You would be interested in Section 3 "Chain conditions" and Section 4 "Complete reduciblility."  When the group is infinite, the group ring is not Artinian regardless of $R$.

Comment: @rschwieb Thank you a lot!

Comment: @lisyarus No problem! If you like group rings, then Connell's paper/thesis are a must-read.

Comment: @rschwieb I certainly do like them, thank you!

Comment: @rschwieb Probably worth it to include this reference in the answer, for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @rschwieb: Certainly a trivial question but why the group ring $\mathbb{C}[\Gamma]$ is semisimple if and only if all $\mathbb{C}$-representations of $\Gamma$ are semisimple?

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux Well, my understanding is that "$\mathbb C$ representation of $\Gamma$" just means "$\mathbb C[\Gamma]$ module", and in that case, yes, the ring is semisimple iff all of its modules are semisimple.